# Disable of button works only first time and when i refresh a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using following code to disable the button if my textarea is empty but it works only first time and when i refresh the whole page, after taking first input i clear the textarea but the button will not disable...
what is wrong in my code PLEASE HELP...

html code is

```
<div id='box'>
                 <form id="stat">
                     <textarea type="text" name="status" id="status" placeholder="Anything You Want To Say...?"></textarea>
                 </form>     
                <button id='statbtn' type="submit" onclick="update()">Update</button>
             </div>
```

i am using this code to display the status and to refresh my textarea in same function as

```
function update() {
        var x,y;
        x=document.getElementById("stat");
        y=x.elements["status"].value;
        document.getElementById("bigbox").innerHTML += "<div id='box1'>"+ y + "</div>";
        $('#status').val('');
    }
```

using this code to disable the button

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#statbtn').prop('disabled',true);
$('#status').keyup(function(){
    $('#statbtn').prop('disabled', this.value == "" ? true : false);     
})
```

});

i had doubt about refreshing line of js so i used jquery code but also button not disabled at next all times.

Comment: Could you please also post your html? When you say refresh, you mean to load the whole page from start (F5)?

Comment: please see now,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that something like the following snippet does what you are looking for. I used plain JavaScript. Apparently, you could use jQuery to do the same thing. However, keep in mind that a good practice is to use only of them for doing the same thing. I mean it's better using plain JavaScript - document.getElementById and the rest corresponding methods of document - to grab your elements rather than using for the half of them plain JavaScript and for the rest of them jQuery.

```js
// We grab the elements of our UI.
var btn = document.getElementById('statbtn');
var stat = document.getElementById("status");
var bigBox = document.getElementById("bigbox")

// The function that is called on statbtn click event.
function update() {
    var status = stat.value;
    bigBox.innerHTML += "<div id='box1'>"+ status + "</div>";
    stat.value = '';
    btn.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
}

// Register the event listeners.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    btn.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
});

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    update();
});

stat.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    var btn = document.getElementById('statbtn');
    if(this.value){
        btn.removeAttribute('disabled','');
    } else {
        btn.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
    }
});
```

```html
<div id='box'>
    <form id="stat">
        <textarea type="text" name="status" id="status" placeholder="Anything You Want To Say...?"></textarea>
    </form>     
    <button id='statbtn' type="submit">Update</button>
</div>
<div id='bigbox'>
</div>
```

Comment: but sir, same problem is occur here that update button is disabled only for first time after that it is not disabled for all time...

Comment: @mayureshpatil The button is disabled the first time, the time you type something in the text area and you hit the button, the time you delete everything in the text area and last the time you refresh the page. Isn't that you are looking for?

Comment: no, i want disable that button at every time after i have updated my status it means that button should be disabled yet my textarea is not filled.

Comment: @mayureshpatil I lose something here. Did you run the snippet? Could you please specify what diverges form that you expect. How do you update your status? You write something in the text area and then you hit the button. This has as a result the text area to be cleared, the status to be appended in another div and your button to be disabled. You can verify this by running the above snippet. So what's different from the expected result? Thanks

Comment: yes sir i had run the snippet when you provided, in snippet also the update button is disable at the first time only. when i run the snippet a button is disabled k, but at next time button is not going disabled. I copied your all code in my src but their also that button is going to disable at first time(when i run) and when i refreshing my whole page...

Comment: @mayureshpatil You don't have to call me sir, my name is Christos :) Apologies...I should stop writing for today code. I had missed to add the corresponding code through which we disable the button on update. I am sorry :( Please have a look now. It should be ok now.

Comment: hello @Christos can you solve my one more problem that How to get new updated status at up and old-one below new status? Here new updated status displayed below old-one(i.e. one below another) but, i need recently updated status should displayed at up and old should display below new....Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will work :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#statbtn').prop('disabled',true);
     // textarea is the id of your textbox. 
    $('#textarea').change(function(){
      if($('#textarea').val() == ""){
      $('#statbtn').prop('disabled',true);
      }else{
      $('#statbtn').prop('disabled',false);
      }
  })
})
```

Comment: nope...! now, that update button is disabled whole time even after i filled my text area...

Comment: This is a change event, so it should be enabled after u click outside the textbox.

Comment: I want to disable my update button every time, yet my textarea is not filled, so how can i do this?